# Eclipse gives "Task List Indexer" has encountered.." error message

Tags: eclipse, list, task

This is using Kepler service release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

Also below that:
An internal error occurred during : "Task List Indexer".

I have tried restoring past task lists but does not work.
Refresh Indexes does not work.

Also :
Typing key word in "Find" field gives this:

"Refresh Filter" has encountered a problem"
"An internal errors occurred"

Below that:
"An internal error has occurred.
 For input string: "My MacBook Pro.gen"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by changing mylyn folder location in preferences. 
Imported old task lists.
It worked!
Moved working folder back to original location.
Changed path in preferences back.